# Identifying which input triggered event handler from a group (array)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of checkboxes with the same name attribute..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="someDude" value="true" > Joe
<input type="checkbox" name="someDude" value="true" > Jack
<input type="checkbox" name="someDude" value="true" > Ralph
```

And I am getting these guys as an array through jQuery and assigining  an event handler for their onChange events like so..

```
 var myJQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
var dudes = myJQuery('input[name=someDude]');

for (var i = 0; i < dudes.length; i++) {
   dudes[i].onchange = function (e) {
    alert("I am " + this.name);
 }
}
```

Is there a way in the event handler onChange function to know which of them was clicked? Since their names are all the same, I can't simply do what I am trying. Even if I can get the index, that would be sufficient.

It would be great if we can do it without adding any more HTML.

Comment: `this` is the one clicked. of course alerting the name would be the same since they have the same name. what are you trying to do?

Comment: it makes no sense at all to have three checkboxes with the same name

Comment: @JaromandaX - Why not? if order is of no importance, then posting such a form could simplify parsing

Comment: @Amit posting such a form would post what exactly?

Comment: @JaromandaX: It would post the same name several times, with the same value. So yes, *with those values*, it doesn't make much sense. If the values were different, however, it could be reasonable (since it's perfectly valid to send `name=firstValue&name=secondValue`).

Comment: I did mean to say with the same name AND value - but I guess you'd see someDude=true 0 to 3 times in the submitted paramters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way in the event handler onChange function to know which of them was clicked?

Yes, `this` is the one that was clicked. So normally, you don't need to do things like getting its index. You *can*, though, using [`index(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element):

```
var index = dudes.index(this);
```

But again, you usually don't need to. For instance, this shows the value of the text node following the clicked element:

```js
var myJQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
var dudes = myJQuery('input[name=someDude]');

for (var i = 0; i < dudes.length; i++) {
  dudes[i].onchange = function (e) {
    alert("I am " + this.name + ", " + this.nextSibling.nodeValue);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="someDude" value="true" > Joe
<input type="checkbox" name="someDude" value="true" > Jack
<input type="checkbox" name="someDude" value="true" > Ralph
```

*(I wouldn't actually recommend getting the following node's value like that, it's just an example demonstrating that `this` refers to the actual element clicked. I'd put the input and its associated label in a `label` element, then use the label's `.text()`.)*

---

Note that there's a much simpler way to attach a click handler to those elements, and one that avoids unnecessarily creating functions in a loop:

```
var myJQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
var dudes = myJQuery('input[name=someDude]');

dudes.on("change", function(e) {
    alert("I am " + this.name);
});
```

`this` still works as shown earlier: It refers to the actual element related to the click.

Answer (score 0):

`this` will give you the object that was interacted with.

Your problem is that there is very little to distinguish between them.

The sensible approach would be to do something that would let you do that, even if JS failed and the data was sent to the server as a regular form submission.

Give them different values.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="someDude" value="Joe"> Joe
```

Then you can examine:

```
this.value
```

Comment: but it's adding an HTML attribute. he said: "It would be great if we can do it without adding any more HTML."

Comment: it's changing an existing attribute, not adding anything

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="someDude"]').on('click', function() {
    alert("My index is: " + $(this).index());
}
```

Have a look at [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use an immediately invoked function expression to create a scope, so that each event handler will have its own variable for the index:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dudes.length; i++) {
  (function(i){
    dudes[i].onchange = function (e) {
      alert("I am number " + i);
    }
  })(i);
}
```